# XML read/change/save vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, save

Is there an easy way to change the IP addresses in the xml below?

My idea is to load first the "Connection name" in a listbox and then the IP address.
Then make 3th listbox where they can add the new IP address.

And then save the new XML file

```
<CSD>
<Version>
 <Version>2.0.1</Version>
 <fileVersion>2.0</fileVersion>
 </Version>
<Connections>
<Connection name="Con1">
<Property name="attributes">
 <title>Product1</title>
 <ipaddress>10.79.44.33</ipaddress>
 <ipport>80</ipport>
 </Property>
 </Connection>
<Connection name="Con2">
<Property name="attributes">
 <title>Product2</title>
 <ipaddress>10.79.44.34</ipaddress>
 <ipport>80</ipport>
 </Property>
 </Connection>
<Connection name="Con3">
<Property name="attributes">
 <title>Productq</title>
 <ipaddress>10.79.44.35</ipaddress>
 <ipport>80</ipport>
 </Property>
 </Connection>
 </Connections>
</CSD>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim xml As String = _
            "<CSD>" & _
                "<Version>" & _
                    "<Version>2.0.1</Version>" & _
                    "<fileVersion>2.0</fileVersion>" & _
                "</Version>" & _
                "<Connections>" & _
                    "<Connection name=""Con1"">" & _
                        "<Property name=""attributes"">" & _
                            "<title>Product1</title>" & _
                            "<ipaddress>10.79.44.33</ipaddress>" & _
                            "<ipport>80</ipport>" & _
                        "</Property>" & _
                    "</Connection>" & _
                    "<Connection name=""Con2"">" & _
                        "<Property name=""attributes"">" & _
                            "<title>Product2</title>" & _
                            "<ipaddress>10.79.44.34</ipaddress>" & _
                            "<ipport>80</ipport>" & _
                        "</Property>" & _
                    "</Connection>" & _
                    "<Connection name=""Con3"">" & _
                        "<Property name=""attributes"">" & _
                            "<title>Productq</title>" & _
                            "<ipaddress>10.79.44.35</ipaddress>" & _
                            "<ipport>80</ipport>" & _
                        "</Property>" & _
                    "</Connection>" & _
                "</Connections>" & _
            "</CSD>"
        Dim csd As XElement = XElement.Parse(xml)
        Dim ipAddresses As List(Of XElement) = csd.Descendants("ipaddress").ToList()
        Dim subAddress As String = "10.79.40"
        Dim address = 1
        For Each ipAddress As XElement In ipAddresses
            ipAddress.Value = subAddress & "." & address.ToString
            address += 1
        Next ipAddress
    End Sub

End Module
```